# Spring Mysql not using application.properties file data correctly on remote IPs

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to build a web app, using spring.
No problem after all trying and erroring. i'm just learning it for now.

but, just in first steps i stumbled with a problem that could not let me proceed.

in my application.properties, i set up my remote mysql server, as shown by the spring.io tutorial

```
/src/main/resources/application.properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://54.234.45.12:3306/*DBNAME*
spring.datasource.username=*user*
spring.datasource.password=*pass*
```

but when running springboot app, it show the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'springuser'@'189-45-120-154.user.veloxzone.com.br' (using password:
>   YES)

which, by the way, is my own IP, not the remote one.

and i cant make it point to the remote.

using localhost,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*DBNAME*
```

changes the output to:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'springuser'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

I can't understand why is not pointing on the internet.
this is an amazon AWS IP, which i can connect remotely with no problems...

(ps.: IPs are changed for obvious reasons)

thanks in advance.

path of file:

Comment: What are the user permission on mysql database?

Comment: @Nambari the permissions are: 
`Grants for springuser@* | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'springuser'@'*'|GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `backend`.* TO 'springuser'@'*'`

Comment: why the privileges on database would affect the ip used by the mysql driver??

Comment: That IP you are seeing could be AWS private IP, it has no relation with privileges. But exception is very clear that it is failing due to USER don't have proper privileges.

Comment: i am sure that is the public IP.

Comment: @Nambari, the user is failing the privileges, but it is trying on `my local IP` and it will never have privileges because i dont have that user on my local mysql.

Comment: Where is your 54.234.45.12 hosted? On EC2 behind ELB?

Comment: the big question is, why it points to **89-45-120-154.user.veloxzone.com.br** when my file points to **mysql://54.234.45.12:3306/*DBNAME***?

Comment: it is hosted on lightsail aws. but i had used it for JavaEE projects with no problems. the IP/port is reachable.

Comment: 1) My guess is your code reading from somewhere else not from the file you are thinking of, if this case is eliminated 2) Do you have any "hosts" file modifications on your local which has dummy mapping to IP VS DNS, if this is eliminated 3) How is AWS/Remote side configured, I mean are there any forwards etc.,

Comment: i guess youre perfectly correct with Number 1. but as i'm new to SpringMVC i cant find where it's designed to override external IPs as local FQDN.

Comment: No, Spring won't do anything except it tries to resolve IP/DNS. Quick way to validate whether data is being read from the file or not is, change IP to something else and see you still get ....user.vlex....com, if yes, that validates properties are not being read. Spring looks for certain folder structure to read properties files from. You might need to quickly google about it. Apart from this, make sure in your code you don't have this .....user.veloxzone....... is not hard coded anywhere.

Comment: it is acting completely weird. because: if the IP is localhost, it goes localhost OK. If the IP is remoteIP with MySQL installation, it points to my local FQDN. If the ip doesn't have mysql, like for ex. google.com:3306 it justs hangs and nothing happens. no exceptions, no errors

Comment: @Nambari MAN I JUST FIGURED OUT! that message is coming from my remote MySQL server pointing me that MY IP is not authorized of accessing that account remotely. Man I'm so dumb!... thanks for the brain massage!

Comment: Glad you figured out, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**i had a trailing space in my password field.**

sorry about that, internet!

I appreciate the effort!